# Is $Y := \{(x, \cos\frac{1}{x}) :\, 0 < x \leq 1\}$ compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Is $Y := \{(x, \cos\frac{1}{x}) :\, 0 < x \leq 1\}$ compact?

I have a lot of theorems about compactness. But I am not sure which one to use and how to solve it and I couldn't find similar example on the internet. Can anybody help me?

Comment: do you know that, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, a set if compact if and only if it is closed and bounded?

Comment: I guess Y is closed and bounded( because cos function and x definition) So Y is compact? Am i right?

Comment: No. Which criteria do you know to check whether a set is closed?

Comment: I am looking limit points

Comment: then have a look at the two answers you got.

Comment: A continuous image of a compact set is compact, so if $Y$ is compact so is $(0,1]$, which is clearly (?) false. The cosine is not important here.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Prove that $Y$ is not closed by exhibiting a sequence $(x_n)$ of $(0,1]$ such that $(x_n,\cos(\frac{1}{x_n}))\to (0,1)\notin Y.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what happens as $x \to 0+$?